# Supertokens - revoke another user's session without signing him off

Tags: authentication

I am using supertokens for authetication. Upon changing another user's permissions, I revoke his session which will cause his role to be updated after his current active token runs it's lifetime limit.
This causes the other user to be logged off at that point.
I would like his role to be updated (i.e. his session re created), but without logging him out and asking him again for his credentials.
Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I will answer this question assuming that you are using the NodeJS SDK. If not, the answer overall still applies, but the function's name will change.

What you want is possible. I assume that you are strong that user's role in the access token, so instead of revoking the other user's session, you should use the `updateAccessTokenPayload` function from the SDK:

```
import Session from "supertokens-node/recipe/session";


async function updateRoleOfOtherUser(userId: string) {
      // we first get all the sessionHandles (string[]) for a user
      let sessionHandles = await Session.getAllSessionHandlesForUser(userId);

      // we update all the session's Access Token payloads for this user
      sessionHandles.forEach(async (handle) => {
            let currAccessTokenPayload = (await Session.getSessionInformation(handle)).accessTokenPayload;

            await Session.updateAccessTokenPayload(handle,
                  { role: "newRole", ...currAccessTokenPayload }
            );
      })
}
```

The update the role will take into affect when their session refreshes, and they won't be logged out.

If you want the update to take affect immediately, you can maintain a cache on your side marking all the session handles that need to be refreshed early. On successful verification of of any such session that contains those session handles, you can send a 401 to the frontend forcing a session refresh and causing an update in their role.

Comment: Okay, this updates the role in the backend, but still requires refreshing the page for the changes to apply on the client side. Do I miss something in the frontend?

Comment: If you add the caching mechanism explained in the answer, the user doesn't actually need to refresh the page. The next API call from the frontend will cause a session refresh and will update the user's role immediately in the session.

Comment: If you do not implement the caching mechanism, then the user will have to wait for their access token to expire and the session to refresh naturally.

Comment: Thanks. I think the one thing that I am still missing is some mechanism that will cause the frontend to update the role and re render the app after the old token has expired. I'm reading the token payload from useSessionContext() and it does not update. For instance, how would the frontend know that the token payload has changed?

Comment: Oh right! There is a bug about that: https://github.com/supertokens/supertokens-auth-react/issues/397. Until it is fixed, you can use the getAccessTokenPayloadSecurely function exposed by the session recipe on the frontend. We will work on fixing the bug this week or next week.

Comment: "On successful verification of of any such session that contains those session handles, you can send a 401 to the frontend forcing a session refresh and causing an update in their role" That does update the role, but session handle (and token) remains unchanged, so this causes an infinite loop. Is the session handle supposed to be changed after receiving a 401? If so what might cause it to remain unchanged in my app? @Rishabh

Comment: The session handle should not change. However, the access token of the session will change and contain the new role - is the access token not changing?

Comment: Okay, sorry, that seems good, the access token does change. Generally, when sending a 401 from the api, how can I avoid an infinite loop? Is there a way to stop it from re-sending the request if the status is 401?

Comment: You can send a status code other than 401. Or you could change the session expiry code that supertokens uses (frontend and backend config for this)